# Division of tranformations of Uniform

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let $U_1 \sim U(0,1)$,  $U_2 \sim U(0,1)$, $X_1 = U_1^{1/\alpha}$ and $X_2 = U_2^{1/\beta}$

$U_1$ is independent of $U_2$ and $X_1 +X_2 \leq 1$

Show that: $$\dfrac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2} \sim Beta(\alpha, \beta)$$

My attempt to solve this question was the following:

$$P\Bigg(\dfrac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2} < x\Bigg) = P\Bigg(\dfrac{X_1}{X_2} < \dfrac{x}{1-x}\Bigg)$$

$$P(X_1<x_1) = P(U^{1/\alpha} < x_1) = P(U < x_1^\alpha) = x_1^\alpha = F_{X_1}(x_1)$$

$$P(X_2<x_2) = P(U^{1/\beta} < x_2) = P(U < x_2^\beta) = x_2^\beta=F_{X_2}(x_2)$$

So, the joint distribution is the following:

$$f(x_1, x_2) = \alpha x_1^{\alpha-1}\beta x_2^{\beta-1}$$

And I proceeded to use the Jacobian method:

$$W = \dfrac{X_1}{X_2};     V = X_1+X_2$$

So
$$X_1 = \dfrac{VW}{1+W};  X_2 = \dfrac{V}{1+W} $$

So the Jacobian matrix will be:

$$J=\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{-v}{(1+w)^2} & \dfrac{1}{1+w}\\\\
\dfrac{v}{(1+w)^2} & \dfrac{w}{1+w}
\end{bmatrix}$$

And the absolute value of the determinant is:

$$|\dfrac{-vw}{(1+w)^3} - \dfrac{v}{(1+w)^3}| = \dfrac{v}{(1+w)^2}$$

$$g(w,v) = \alpha\Big( \dfrac{vw}{1+w} \Big)^{\alpha-1} \beta \Big( \dfrac{v}{1+w} \Big)^{\beta-1} \dfrac{v}{(1+w)^2} $$

$$g(w) = \int_{0}^{1} g(w,v) dv = \dfrac{\alpha\beta w^{\alpha-1}}{(1+w)^{\alpha+\beta}} \int_{0}^{1} v^{\alpha +\beta-1} dv =\dfrac{\alpha\beta w^{\alpha-1}}{(1+w)^{\alpha+\beta}} \dfrac{1}{\alpha+\beta} $$

And now I think that I did something wrong, beacause when try to find the CDF I didn't get nothing similar to the beta CDF.

Comment: I do not see how "$U_1$ is independent of $U_2$ and $X_1 +X_2 \leq 1$" works

Comment: I don;t know either. This was on the question proposed. THe only thing that I extracted was that as X1 + X2 < 1, so V<1.

Comment: Simulating this is interesting.  To get it work, it seems you can choose $X_1$ and $X_2$ as described , so independent at this stage, but then reject those pairs where $X_1+X_2 \gt 1$ (or $>$ some smaller value) in which case $X_1$ and $X_2$ are no longer independent.

Comment: Perhaps, you could write that $U_1$ is independent from $U_2$. Show that $$ \dfrac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2} \mid \{X_1+X_2 \le 1\} \sim \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha, \beta).$$

Comment: I suspect that $\dfrac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2} \mid \{X_1+X_2=k\} \sim \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$ when $k\le 1$

Comment: The reason you need the condition  $V=X_1+X_2\le 1$ is that in those cases $R=\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}$ has the support $[0,1]$, while if $V=v>1$ then $R$ has the support $[1-\frac1v, \frac1v]$.  You have said the joint density $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)=\alpha x_1^{\alpha-1}\beta x_2^{\beta-1}$, so $f_{X_1,X_2}(rv,(1-r)v)=\alpha (rv)^{\alpha-1}\beta ((1-r)v)^{\beta-1}$ $=\alpha r^{\alpha-1}\beta (1-r)^{\beta-1}\, v^{\alpha+\beta-2}$ and you can integrate out the $v$ term leaving the desired Beta density